# Obtener parte de una url Selenium Python

Tags: python, url, selenium

Tengo esta URL y quiero solo obtener una parte de ella:

```
https://onevideo.aol.com/#/inventorysource/1024374?makeDuplicate=true
```

La parte que quiero obtener es el id:1024374
para luego introducirlo en esta otra url:

```
https://onevideo.aol.com/inventory_sources/get_adtag_urls_export?secure=0&ft=EXCEL&piggyback_type=ANY&id=1024374&at=MOBILE_WEB&_sid=60c7302b-9ede-4308-93f6-014975706aff
```

Explico un poco para despejar dudas. Con selenium soy redirigido a la primer URL. Ahi quiero obtener el ID de la url. Pense hacerlo con `driver.current_url` pero obtengo toda la url. Luego necesito que el ID que obtenga lo introduzca a la segunda url donde va el ID.

Trabajo con Python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes varias opciones, desde usar `str.split` a expresiones regulares, o puedes usar el módulo [`urlparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) junto a [`str.rpartition`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rpartition):

```
import urlparse

url = 'https://onevideo.aol.com/sd/inventorysource/1024374?makeDuplicate=true'
url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(url,  allow_fragments = False)
id = url_parts[2].rpartition('/')[2]
print(id)
```

En Python 3 el módulo es `urllib.parse`.

Si tus urls tienen siempre la misma estructura puedes simplemente usar `str.rpartition` dos veces:

```
url = 'https://onevideo.aol.com/sd/inventorysource/1024374?makeDuplicate=true'
id = url.rpartition('/')[2].rpartition('?')[0] 
print(id)
```

`str.rpartition` divide una cadena usando la última ocurrencia del separador proporcionado como argumento. Retorna una tupla con tres elementos donde el segundo es el separador, el primero lo que queda a su izquierda y el tercero lo que queda a su derecha.

---

**Edición:**

Para obtener la URL como una cadena solo necesitas usar el atributo `current_url`:

```
url = driver.current_url
```

Para crear tu nueva url formatea la cadena:

```
base = "https://onevideo.aol.com/inventory_sources/get_adtag_urls_export?secure=0&ft=EXCEL&piggyback_type=ANY&id={}&at=MOBILE_WEB&_sid=60c7302b-9ede-4308-93f6-014975706aff"
new_url = base.format(id)
```

Comment: EL urlparse puedo usarlo en el mismo programa que corro selenium?

Comment: `url = str(driver.current_url)
    url_parts = urlparse.urlparse(url,  allow_fragments = False)
    id = url_parts[2].rpartition('/')[2]
    print(id)` Ese seria mi codigo para obtenerlo, pero no me estaria funcionando. Ademas tendria que dsp pegar ese id en la otra url que postie luego...

Comment: Me salta este error: `global name 'urlparse' is not defined`

Comment: Ahi lo obtuve, y ahora como lo introduzco a la url 2 que necesito?

Comment: Anduvo todo ok! Muchas gracias. Ahora te hago otra cosulta que tiene que ver con esto, esa url base me descarga un archivo xlsx con un nombre por default que es Ad tag download.xlsx, hay forma de que le pueda cambiar el nombre y me lo descargue con el nombre que quiera??

Comment: @MartinBouhier si no me equivoco eso no se puede hacer con Selenium, lo que si puedes hacer es esperar a que se descargue y entonces usar Python para renombrarlo, vía `os.rename` por ejemplo. Otra opción es usar python para descargar el archivo via `urllib.urlretrieve`: `import urllib` y luego `urllib.urlretrieve(url, "/choose/your/file_name.xlsx")`

Comment: Usando urllib tendría que cambiar todo mi programa para urllib en vez de selenium lo cual no puedo hacerlo de esa forma. Y con rename seria lo más acertado verdad?

Comment: No, simplemente importas y luego descargas con `urllib.urlretrieve(url, "file_name.xlsx")`. Solo usas urllib para descargar. No tienes que tocar nada de tu código, solo que a la hora de descargar la url que creamos antes con la id se la pasas a urllib tal y como te muestro en vez de descargar vía Selenium.  Acabo de descargar el xlsx de tu url ejemplo con este método, no debes tener problemas, descarga y renombra sin problemas :). No se necesitas ni logearte siquiera via urllib.

Comment: si el nombre que necesito que tenga el archivo esta en una variable como: `d = "archivo_martin"` como podria hacer para que quede `archivo_martin.xlsx` dentro de `urllib.urlretrieve(url, "file_name.xlsx")`

Comment: `urllib.urlretrieve(url, "{}.xlsx".format(d))`. Esto te lo descargará en el directorio de trabajo actual. Si deseas descargar en otro directorio pasa la ruta: `urllib.urlretrieve(url, "/home/martin/Documentos/{}.xlsx".format(d))`

Comment: Lo intente pero me da error: `[Errno 22] invalid mode ('wb') or filename: ' Media MW $ 1.5 |.xlsx'`

Comment: se que la | podria ser el causante pero pasa que yo obtengo mi nombre del diccionario. Necesito que sea asi. Hay alguna forma de saltarlo de ultima? Saltarlo me refiero a que no lo muestre en el nombre del file.xlsx

Comment: @MartinBouhier si solo tienes ese carácter inválido puedes eliminarlo usando `str.replace` junto a los espacios de principio y final  con `str.strip` (si lo deseas). Con `d = d.replace("|", "").strip()` obtienes `Media MW $ 1.5`.

Comment: Increible todo lo que sabes, siempre me salvas las papas! Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

Agrego el método de las expresiones regulares aunque en tu caso ya que se trata de urls, lo mejor es la solución de FJSevilla.

```
import re

url = "https://onevideo.aol.com/#/inventorysource/1024374?makeDuplicate=true"
m = re.search('(^.*\/)([0-9]{7})(\?.*$)', url)

print m.group(1)
print m.group(2)
print m.group(3)

https://onevideo.aol.com/#/inventorysource/
1024374
?makeDuplicate=true
```

Como verás el segundo grupo es el id que buscas. La explicación es:

```
(^         # Primer grupo, desde el comienzo
.*         # Cualquier caracter
\/)        # Hasta la primer barra antes del segundo grupo
([0-9]{7}) # 2do grupo solo 7 números, puedes hacer también {1,7} de 1 a 7 números
(\?        # 3er grupo desde el ?
.*         # Cualquier caracter
$)         # Hasta el final de la cadena
```